# openwrt create ovpn files

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

i am trying to setup an openvpn server to my openwrt router. i would like to create a single ovpn file for each user, instead of multiple files for each user. in my debian machines i use the Nyr/openvpn-install script that does everything automatically. is there something similar for openwrt?

Has anyone any ideas on how to do that?